# Faster way to iterate all keys and values in redis db

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a db with about 350,000 keys. Currently my code just loops through all keys and gets its value from the db.

However this takes almost 2 minutes to do, which seems really slow, `redis-benchmark` gave 100k reqs/3s.

I've looked at pipelining but I need each value returned so that I end up with a dict of key, value pairs.

At the moment I'm thinking of using threading in my code if possible to speed this up, is this the best way to handle this usecase?

Here's the code I have so far.

```
import redis, timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
count = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=9)
keys = count.keys()

data = {}

for key in keys:
    value = count.get(key)
    if value:
        data[key.decode('utf-8')] = int(value.decode('utf-8'))

elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time

print('Time to read {} records: '.format(len(keys)), elapsed)
```

Comment: It sounds like you query the db for each item you want. Can you instead make some bigger aggregate query to get multiple values at once?

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is pipelining but it returns a list of the values and I need to match the key with the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the fastest way is doing all of this inside [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Next, recommended approach to iterate all keys is [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan). It would not iterate faster than `KEYS`, but will allow Redis to process some other actions in between, so it will help with overall application behavior.

The script will be something like `local data={} local i=1 local mykeys=redis.call(\"KEYS\",\"*\") for k=1,#mykeys do local tmpkey=mykeys[k] data[i]={tmpkey,redis.call(\"GET\",tmpkey)} i=i+1 end return data`, but it will fail if you have keys inaccessible with GET (like sets, lists). You need to add error handling to it. If you need sorting, you can do it either in LUA directly, or later on the client side. The second will be slower, but would not let other users of redis instance wait.

Sample output:

```
127.0.0.1:6370> eval "local data={} local i=1 local mykeys=redis.call(\"KEYS\",\"*\") for k=1,#mykeys do local tmpkey=mykeys[k] data[i]={tmpkey,redis.call(\"GET\",tmpkey)} i=i+1 end return data" 0
1) 1) "a"
   2) "aval"
2) 1) "b"
   2) "bval"
3) 1) "c"
   2) "cval"
4) 1) "d"
   2) "dval"
5) 1) "e"
   2) "eval"
6) 1) "f"
   2) "fval"
7) 1) "g"
   2) "gval"
8) 1) "h"
   2) "hval"
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use EVAL in python? It seems to require lua scripting. I'm testing using pipelining to get all the values when iterating through keys, it takes about 6 seconds to get all the values for all the 350k+ keys, do you know if the values will be in the exact same order as the keys?

Comment: The values (using KEYS) will be in the exact same order as you get in the line `keys = count.keys()`. Redis's reference documentation doesn't say anything about order in which they are returned.

Comment: On the other hand, SCAN explicitly does not guarantee order and consistence.

Comment: So I'll definitely need to use keys, it's not that bad, it takes about 14s to get all the keys. I can't help feeling this should also be faster though.

Comment: ps. be sure to have enough spare memory. If you need streaming, you can compose a more elaborate script using SCAN, but you'll have to deal with inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this

Comment: Reminder not to use `redis.call(KEYS, *)` in production if you have a few million keys it will lock your redis until it completes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and ended up using`KEYS` and `MGET` to iterate multiple keys at the same time:

```py
import redis
url='redis://my.redis.url'
query='product:*'

client = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(url, decode_responses=True)
keys = client.keys(query)

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

partitions = list(chunks(keys, 10000))

data = []
for keys in partitions:
    values = client.mget(keys)
    data.extend(zip(keys, values))

print(len(data))
```

[I've written a blog on showing progress while writing the result to a file](https://keestalkstech.com/2020/08/reading-multiple-key-values-from-redis/#python-scripting-to-the-rescue).

This code is the base for the [redis-mass-get Python package](https://pypi.org/project/redis-mass-get/). It could be used to do the same, like this:

```py
from redis_mass_get import RedisQuery

# pluralize will return the result or None
q = RedisQuery("redis://my.amazing.redis.url")

# query data 
data = q.query("product:*")
# data is returned as:
# [(key1, value1), (key2, value2)]
```