# Is there any better way to get all values from redis?

Tags: c#, redis, async-await

I know it's not the best idea to get all values from a cache, but I have a special use case for an internal tool.

I have the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetAllStoreEntries()
{
    var keys = RedisStore.Server.Keys(pattern: $"{GetCompletePrefix()}:*", pageSize: pageSize).ToList();
    foreach (var subList in Split(keys, pageSize))
    {
        var subKeys = subList.ToArray();
        var values = RedisStore.RedisCache.StringGet(subKeys);  <---------
        for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = values[i];
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                var svalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<V>(value);
                yield return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(GetKKey(subKeys[i]), svalue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the marked position I want to use StringGetAsync, but I have no idea how to restructure the code that I can use it.

How can I rewrite GetAllStoreEntries, so that it fetches the splitted keys-list in parallel?

Comment: You can start from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) and [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: true `IEnumerable<...>` isn't really very amenable to concurrency (nor to await); what kind of volume are we talking about here? It *looks* like you're using SE.Redis there, which supports full pipelinining over async, but... you can't use an iterator block (`yield return`) with `async`, so that doesn't necessarily help. SE.Redis also supports `MGET`, but that will result in one redis op; so again: what is the data volume here?

Comment: Hi Marc, it's SE.Redis. I splitted the list of keys because I get a timeout. There are >250000 entries.

Comment: check out this, but it's a dangerous path https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488373/78569 maybe you can combine this with Marc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your best bet here might be to populate a dictionary using an overlapped pipeline, something like (not exact code, I'm making this up as I go):

```
async Task<Dictionary<K, V>> GetAllStoreEntries()
{
    var keys = RedisStore.Server.Keys(pattern: $"{GetCompletePrefix()}:*", pageSize: pageSize);
    var result = new Dictionary<K, V>();
    const int OVERLAP = 10; // the number of in-flight operations
    await keys.Pipe<RedisKey, RedisValue>(OVERLAP,
        key => redis.StringGet(key),
        (key, val) => result.Add(GetKey(key), Deserialize(val)));
    return result;
}
```

using (untested):

```
public static async Task Pipe<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int pipeLength,
    Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> map, Action<TSource, TResult> reduce)
{
    var buffer = new (TSource val, Task<TResult> task)[pipeLength];

    uint index = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var newTask = map(item);
        if (newTask.IsCompleted)
        {   // completed synchronously; check for error and move on
            reduce(item, newTask.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            var thisIndex = index++ % pipeLength;
            var oldPair = buffer[thisIndex];
            if (oldPair.task != null) reduce(oldPair.val, await oldPair.task);
            buffer[thisIndex] = (item, newTask);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pipeLength; i++)
    {
        var oldPair = buffer[(i + index) % pipeLength];
        if (oldPair.task != null) reduce(oldPair.val, await oldPair.task);
    }
}
```

What this *attempts* to do is:

- iterate the keys lazily - no `ToList()`
- have multiple commands in flight at a time
- process the results efficiently and sequentially
- as an async operation that populates a dictionary

**Completely** untested, but... in theory it should work! And: it doesn't pay latency per key, thanks to overlapped pipelined async operations. Increasing `OVERLAP` may reduce latency delays further, as may increasing `pageSize`.

Comment: It's working, but it's running much slower than my code. If we can combine this with not asking for every key separately...